# How might excess links/libraries affect the executable output during compilation?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

For instance, if I were to link the object "example.o" with

```
-L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lGL -lGLU -lm -lglut -lGLEW -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -ldl -lXcursor -lXinerama
```

and the output executable compiled just as well (and perceivably functioned just as well) as when linked only with

```
-lGL -lm -lglfw3
```

how then might the excessive linkages of the former compilation affect an executable for the end user (if at all)? Load/run times? For larger programs (understanding that "example.o" is rather small)?

This question may be for my own edification, admittedly.

Comment: Obviously dependent on the linker, but I imagine the extra libraries have little effect.  Link time will increase marginally as it takes longer to search through all the symbols, but if the extra symbols aren't used and your linker is worth its salt, then executable size and runtime shouldn't be affected at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your compiler driver is passing the "--as-needed" option to the linker by default, then this will make no difference in the resulting binary because the linker will drop the unneeded library dependencies.

The Debian wiki as an extensive article on this: [Debian DSO Linking](https://wiki.debian.org/ToolChain/DSOLinking).

Comment: Thank you for the thought! I'll be reading the article shortly.